# How to configure Gitlab to send emails on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, server, smtp, gitlab

### Here is my problem

- I have installed Gitlab on my server
- When i create a new user for Gitlab, it has to send an email to the new user mail address in order to set a new password
- but the email never leaves
- Should i do something on my ovh account ? (i just took the domain name and a mx plan with 5 emails)
- Should i use something else ?

### Here is what i've done

- /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

  `gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
  gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "ssl0.ovh.net"
  gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
  gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] ='gitlab@domain.com'
  gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] ='xxx'
  gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "ssl0.ovh.net"
  gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
  gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
  gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
  gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
  gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@domain.com'
  gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'no-reply@domain.com'`

### Then i run :

```
$>gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

and

```
$>gitlab-rails console
irb(main):001:0> ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method
=> :smtp
irb(main):003:0> Notify.test_email('xxx@gmail.com', `'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now`
Notify#test_email: processed outbound mail in 690.5ms

Sent mail to xxx@gmail.com (30042.6ms)
Date: Sun, 10 Jun 2018 14:40:16 +0000
From: GitLab <xxx@domain.com>
Reply-To: GitLab <no-reply@domain.com>
To: xxx@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5b1d38507f7f6_43f93fc1ebfdb104528d7@scw-d9ca55.mail>
Subject: Message Subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Message Body</p></body></html>

Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `initialize'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `open'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `tcp_socket'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:552:in `block in do_start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in `start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:109:in `start_smtp_session'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:100:in `deliver!'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:2160:in `do_delivery'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `block in deliver'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.10/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.10/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `deliver'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.10/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
    from (irb):2
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:14:in `require'
    from bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A really good tutorial about ["how to install and configure SMTP server on ubuntu"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

And then, you have to change your SMTP configuration for gitlab in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` with your own SMTP configuration.